# Shell script cut command

Tags: shell, cut

I am trying to cut `ABCservice` and `DEFService` dfrom the array and print them.What am I missing here?

```
  urlArray=('http://server:port/ABCservice/services/ABCservice?wsdl' 'http://server:port/DEFservice/services/DEFservice?wsdl')   
        for url in "${urlArray[@]}"
         do
            service=echo $url|cut -f4 -d/
            echo $service
        done
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ABCService
DEFService
```

Current Output:

```
./test1.sh: line 6: http://server:port/ABCservice/services/ABCservice?wsdl: No such file or directory
./test1.sh: line 6: http://server:port/DEFservice/services/DEFservice?wsdl: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What abut this?

```
service=$(echo $url | cut -d"/" -f4)
echo $service
```

or directly

```
echo $(echo $url | cut -d"/" -f4)
```

The problems in your code:

```
service=echo $url|cut -f4 -d\
```

- to save a command output in a variable, we do it like this: `service=$(command)`.
- your `cut` had `\` as delimiter instead of `/`. Also it is good to wrap it with brackets: `-d "/"`

Answer (score 1):

```
service=$(echo $url | cut -d/ -f6 | cut -d\? -f1)
echo $service
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` string function:

```
for i in "${!urlArray[@]}"; do 
    urlArray[i]="${urlArray[i]%\?*}"
    urlArray[i]="${urlArray[i]##*/}"
    echo ${urlArray[i]}
done



$ urlArray=('http://server:port/ABCservice/services/ABCservice?wsdl' 'http://server:port/DEFservice/services/DEFservice?wsdl') 
$ for i in "${!urlArray[@]}"; do urlArray[i]="${urlArray[i]%\?*}"; urlArray[i]="${urlArray[i]##*/}";  echo ${urlArray[i]} ; done
ABCservice
DEFservice
```

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter should be a forward slash

```
echo 'http://server:port/ABCservice/services/ABCservice?wsdl' | cut -f 4 -d/
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\` is an escape character. Try `\\` instead.

Comment: To avoid espacing chars, use backquotes `\`` instead of double quotes `"`.